# Android 2.1 Import Module facebook sdk 4.11: Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse Project

Tags: android

this is my projec[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSJSt.png)t

[Unable to import 'facebook' sdk 4.11 as module in android 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS5LK.png)i.stack.imgur.com/3vo06.png

plz help me how to resolve this problem

Comment: You are importing it wrong. 
Check if the module you are trying to import is a studio project. If Its a studio project, please import build.gradle file. If the facebook project is an eclipse project then you will need to convert it stuio project first and then import.

Comment: remove the module and try this dependencies ,dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
}

Comment: thank both of you for helping me